# Wifi internet and network acces only via bluetooth adapter

Tags: windows, internet, network-shares, bluetooth, wifi-configuration

I want to have wifi access via my bluetooth adapter. I have a computer without wifi adapter, but i do have a bluetooth adapter (usb). I was wondering how to use my bluetooth adapter as a wifi adapter. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

My computer:
Windows 7 pro
bluetooth 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could tether to a Bluetooth phone for Internet but otherwise Bluetooth is not wifi. The two operate on separate frequencies and at different ranges.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering and this makes it clear to better buy an wifi adapter for usb.